# Scattering from a dirac delta potential in momentum space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, fourier-transform, dirac-delta-distributions

I was curious about solving the reflection and transmission amplitudes for the dirac delta potential barrier using fourier transform.
I'm able to take the fourier transform but I'm unable to interpret the pole prescription that comes up.
I didn't completely understand the following answer: [Poles for a particle scattered in a delta potential](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/121827/)

Comment: Hi ilawid. Welcome to Phys.SE. To reopen the post (v2) consider to be more specific about what you didn't understand in the previous answer.